# Cleanest way to apply filter criteria to the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-maps-api-3

I have a page which has a `Google Maps V3` map and a HTML form with a "Filter" button.

I also have this one big XML file that has complex structure with information about each marker that I will parse as html inside each marker's infobox.

I'm able to read and generate the markers from the XML file and plot them on the map, but I can't wrap my head around filtering the markers on the map.

**What would be the cleanest way** to filter markers on the map, after pressing "Filter" button, that will meet my filtering criteria specified with the HTML form on the page?

My form has one listbox so far:

`Company` - based on what company name you select it should show all of its branches on the map. The XML file has all that information(branch address, lat, lng, phonenumber, comapny it belongs to).

***XML structure:***

```
<markers>
    <marker>
        <company name="ComapnyName">
            <branches>
                <branch>
                    <address>BranchAddress</address>
                    <phone>BranchAddress</phone>
                    <products>
                        <product>
                            <name>ProductName</name>
                            <url>ProductURL</url>
                        </product>
                        <product />
                        <product />
                        ...
                    </products>
                </branch>
                <branch />
                <branch />
                ...
            </branches>
        </company>
    </marker>
    <marker />
    <marker />
    ...
</markers>
```

Comment: Why not set up some arrays and include index references to the markers in each array?  If you filter on the company name, then you should be able to reference the company name in an array, along with it's respective markers.  However, why not move the data in the XML file to a database and use AJAX to request the markers on the fly?  This seems like a much more scalable, efficient, and clean approach.

Comment: @andresf Actually, I'm using a MySQL database. I have a bunch of tables that have relationships between them(foreign keys, associative/joint tables) which hold all that data that I have in my XML too. I use PHP to generate my XML file by making calls to the database. Are you saying that querying database for the search results using AJAX would be better? Won't you strain the database server like that instead of using a huge XML file that gets updated with a cron job every hour or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way to achieve the filtering you describe is to place your markers into an `Array`, traverse the `Array` when the filter settings change, and then either turn the markers **off**:

```
Marker.setMap( null );
```

or **on**:

```
Marker.setMap( map );
```

If you are treating the filters as toggles, you will probably want to crate some state vars to track the filter settings, so that you can also write code similar to this:

```
var filterOptionAbcIsOn = false;
function toggleFilters() {
    if ( filterOptionAbcIsOn ) {
        // loop across the Array and turn the markers off
        filterOptionAbcIsOn = false;
    }
    else {
        // loop across the Array and turn the associated markers on
        filterOptionAbcIsOn = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I have to use something like `documnet.getElementById('IDOfTheControlOnTheForm')` to fetch what value was selected in the listbox(es), or other type of controls, on the form to pass it/use it with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, you will have to retrieve the html `element` state (checked, selected, etc.) in order to know what filter settings have been set. But just as important, you will also need a way to know when the state of an `element` has changed. What I do is: Put a `checkbox` on my page for each filter setting, use jQuery to display each `checkbox` as an `image/button`, and then define a `click` event listener for each so that I can update the map display as the user toggles the filter settings on or off.